# Consolidate matching elements and iterate and separate out elements non matching elements in a collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I'm new to Node\JS and stuck on how to consolidate matching elements and iterate non matching elements in a collecting creating a new collection. I have thus far used lodash to group the data that is pasted(Grouped Input) below but cant figure out how to get Desired Output.

I'm open to using lodash\underscore\javascript or any other library compatible with Node.

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

```js
Grouped Input:

[ { mod_AccountNumber: '0001',
    mod_Id: '123456',
    mod_LastName: 'SMITH',
    mod_FirstName: 'NANCY',
    mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM10',
    mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18',
    mod_AppointmentTime: '0900' },
  { mod_AccountNumber: '0001',
    mod_Id: '123456',
    mod_LastName: 'SMITH',
    mod_FirstName: 'NANCY',
    mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM11',
    mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18',
    mod_AppointmentTime: '0930' },
  { mod_AccountNumber: '0001',
    mod_Id: '654321',
    mod_LastName: 'JONES',
    mod_FirstName: 'NATASHA',
    mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM11',
    mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18',
    mod_AppointmentTime: '0930' },
  { mod_AccountNumber: '0001',
    mod_Id: '654321',
    mod_LastName: 'JONES',
    mod_FirstName: 'NATASHA',
    mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM12',
    mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18',
    mod_AppointmentTime: '1015' }
]

Desired Output:

[ { mod_AccountNumber: '0001',
    mod_Id: '123456',
    mod_LastName: 'SMITH',
    mod_FirstName: 'NANCY',
    mod_AppointmentLocation_1: 'ROOM10',
    mod_AppointmentTime_1:'0900',
    mod_AppointmentLocation_2: 'ROOM11',
    mod_AppointmentTime_2:'0930' },
  { mod_AccountNumber: '0001',
    mod_Id: '654321',
    mod_LastName: 'JONES',
    mod_FirstName: 'NATASHA',
    mod_AppointmentLocation_1: 'ROOM11',
    mod_AppointmentTime_1:'0930',
    mod_AppointmentLocation_2: 'ROOM12',
    mod_AppointmentTime_2:'1015' }
]
```

Comment: Are you stuck with that output format? In general when you're tempted to use variable names with numbers like `mod_AppointmentTime_1` & `mod_AppointmentTime_2` you should be using an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An overall better approach would be to **convert to array** those date/time/locations. But given the current question could do something like this:

```js
const data = [{ mod_AccountNumber: '0001', mod_Id: '123456', mod_LastName: 'SMITH', mod_FirstName: 'NANCY', mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM10', mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18', mod_AppointmentTime: '0900' }, { mod_AccountNumber: '0001', mod_Id: '123456', mod_LastName: 'SMITH', mod_FirstName: 'NANCY', mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM11', mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18', mod_AppointmentTime: '0930' }, { mod_AccountNumber: '0001', mod_Id: '654321', mod_LastName: 'JONES', mod_FirstName: 'NATASHA', mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM11', mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18', mod_AppointmentTime: '0930' }, { mod_AccountNumber: '0001', mod_Id: '654321', mod_LastName: 'JONES', mod_FirstName: 'NATASHA', mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM12', mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18', mod_AppointmentTime: '1015' } ]

const result = _(data)
 .groupBy('mod_Id')
 .values()
 .map(x => _.values(_.transform(x, (r,c,i) => {
   r[c.mod_Id] = _.extend(r[c.mod_Id], {
   mod_Id: c.mod_Id,
   mod_AccountNumber: c.mod_AccountNumber,
   mod_LastName: c.mod_LastName,
   mod_FirstName: c.mod_FirstName,
   [`mod_AppointmentLocation${i+1}`]: c.mod_AppointmentLocation,
   [`mod_AppointmentDate${i+1}`]: c.mod_AppointmentDate,
   [`mod_AppointmentTime${i+1}`]: c.mod_AppointmentTime,
 })}, {})))
 .flatten()
 .value()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The idea is to first group by the `mod_Id` then take the `values` `map` through them and `transform` them to one object. Since you are back into object form you get the `values` and last you `flatten` the array.

Somewhat simpler approach is to go with **ES6** with something like this:

```js
const data = [{ mod_AccountNumber: '0001', mod_Id: '123456', mod_LastName: 'SMITH', mod_FirstName: 'NANCY', mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM10', mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18', mod_AppointmentTime: '0900' }, { mod_AccountNumber: '0001', mod_Id: '123456', mod_LastName: 'SMITH', mod_FirstName: 'NANCY', mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM11', mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18', mod_AppointmentTime: '0930' }, { mod_AccountNumber: '0001', mod_Id: '654321', mod_LastName: 'JONES', mod_FirstName: 'NATASHA', mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM11', mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18', mod_AppointmentTime: '0930' }, { mod_AccountNumber: '0001', mod_Id: '654321', mod_LastName: 'JONES', mod_FirstName: 'NATASHA', mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM12', mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18', mod_AppointmentTime: '1015' } ]

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, c, i) => {
  let _x = r[c.mod_Id] ? r[c.mod_Id]._x : 0
  _x++
  r[c.mod_Id] = Object.assign(r[c.mod_Id] || {}, {
    mod_Id: c.mod_Id,
    mod_AccountNumber: c.mod_AccountNumber,
    mod_LastName: c.mod_LastName,
    mod_FirstName: c.mod_FirstName,
    [`mod_AppointmentLocation${_x}`]: c.mod_AppointmentLocation,
    [`mod_AppointmentDate${_x}`]: c.mod_AppointmentDate,
    [`mod_AppointmentTime${_x}`]: c.mod_AppointmentTime,
    _x
  })
  return r
}, {})).map(({_x, ...rest}) => rest)
console.log(result)
```

The only caveat is that this approach is not pure since it keeps track of the current item number via mutating the object with an `_x` property, which at the end is stripped via the `map`

In case you want to consider going after the array idea things get much simpler then:

```js
const data = [{ mod_AccountNumber: '0001', mod_Id: '123456', mod_LastName: 'SMITH', mod_FirstName: 'NANCY', mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM10', mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18', mod_AppointmentTime: '0900' }, { mod_AccountNumber: '0001', mod_Id: '123456', mod_LastName: 'SMITH', mod_FirstName: 'NANCY', mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM11', mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18', mod_AppointmentTime: '0930' }, { mod_AccountNumber: '0001', mod_Id: '654321', mod_LastName: 'JONES', mod_FirstName: 'NATASHA', mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM11', mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18', mod_AppointmentTime: '0930' }, { mod_AccountNumber: '0001', mod_Id: '654321', mod_LastName: 'JONES', mod_FirstName: 'NATASHA', mod_AppointmentLocation: 'ROOM12', mod_AppointmentDate: '10/26/18', mod_AppointmentTime: '1015' } ]

const result = _.chain(data)
  .reduce((r,c,i) => {
  r[c.mod_Id] = r[c.mod_Id] ? r[c.mod_Id] : {
    mod_Id: c.mod_Id,
    mod_AccountNumber: c.mod_AccountNumber,
    mod_LastName: c.mod_LastName,
    mod_FirstName: c.mod_FirstName,
    schedule: []
  }
  r[c.mod_Id].schedule.push({
    mod_AppointmentLocation: c.mod_AppointmentLocation,
    mod_AppointmentDate: c.mod_AppointmentDate,
    mod_AppointmentTime: c.mod_AppointmentTime
  })
  return r
 }, {})
 .values()
 .value()
 
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks Akrion of detailed suggestions. I like the array idea better and decided to use that. When I cut and paste the code you provide if get "schedule: [ [Object], [Object] ]". I double checked everything:

I'm using Node with lodash 4.17.11

[ { mod_Id: '123456',
    mod_AccountNumber: '0001',
    mod_LastName: 'SMITH',
    mod_FirstName: 'NANCY',
    schedule: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { mod_Id: '654321',
    mod_AccountNumber: '0001',
    mod_LastName: 'JONES',
    mod_FirstName: 'NATASHA',
    schedule: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]

Comment: It seems to work on my end ... here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/akrion/2ekbnwoq/

Comment: Thanks! Before I commented I checked it with JSBin and it works there as well. Interesting, same exact code in Node JS produces [object object]. I even downgraded lodash to 4.17.10.

Comment: Weird. I get working code in Repl as well: https://repl.it/@akrion/arrayNodeJSSample

Comment: just checked your Repl and it produces same results as my node app: 

schedule: [ [Object], [Object] ]

[ { mod_Id: '123456',
    mod_AccountNumber: '0001',
    mod_LastName: 'SMITH',
    mod_FirstName: 'NANCY',
    schedule: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { mod_Id: '654321',
    mod_AccountNumber: '0001',
    mod_LastName: 'JONES',
    mod_FirstName: 'NATASHA',
    schedule: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
=> undefined

Comment: i wonder if it has any thing to do with lodash full package vs the mini that used in jsfiddle, JSBin and here in the code snippet.

Comment: But what is the issue this is simply due to console.log() which outputs `Object` instead of printing the entire object. Simply iterate through them and you will see the values. I updated the repl with `result.map(x => console.log(x.schedule))` on the end and you can see that it is all as expected

Comment: Thanks Akiron. Appreciate all your help. Your code worked well for me.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
const {groupBy, values, merge} = require('lodash');
// input...
const output = values(
    groupBy(input, 'id')
).map(chunks => merge(...chunks));
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged — try adding a little explanation. Also, this doesn't result in the desired format It discards matching keys like `mod_AppointmentLocation`.